# Using concat method with closure in child functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, closures

I want to use `.concat`, not push, inside the scope of a child function then access it higher up the scope chain.

I have here a simple function to list files in a directory after running them through a regex function to filter out certain filenames and filetypes. The following function works fine with the .push array method, but it returns an empty array if I try to use .concat

```
fs.readdir('./schema', function(err,files){
  var filelist = [];
  if(err)
    throw err;
  else{
    var index = files.length;
    while(index>0){
      filelist.concat(isNOTswapfile(files[index]));
      index--;
      }
    console.log(filelist)
    }
  }
)
```

Returns an empty array `[]`

Help is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: How are you using concat? Show us the code that's not working.

Comment: You have to assign the result of concat as it returns a new array.

Comment: @Yatrix sorry, a mod (probably the same one that originally marked this a duplicate) edited my post by copying and pasting my original (and erroneous) post here. I've since re-edited the post. Sorry!

Comment: @changed is there a way to do this without reassignment? I'm trying to apply certain types of programming principles to my code, (such as not using methods that mutate code). Am I wrong in thinking reassignment is a mutation that some programming paradigms may find problematic?

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.push.apply( array1, array2 )` to add to array1 in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` returns you a new Array back. So unless you reassign the `filelist` variable back, it will just remain `[]`

```
while(index>0){
  filelist = filelist.concat(isNOTswapfile(files[index]));
  index--;
}
console.log(filelist)
```

should work just fine.

You can read more on [MDN Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)